# How to use google ads api access on behalf your client

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api

im new in googleads library and im facing a problem

i added the google adswords api library to a new laravel 5.3 .

i make a call and retrieve data using the ini file but when i try to use the access on behalf of your client in
[this wiki of the library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/wiki/API-access-on-behalf-of-your-clients-(web-flow))

but it not working the final part i didnt understand

```
  4.  You can now use the OAuth2 object to make calls using the client library.

use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;

$session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
    ->fromFile()
    ->withOAuth2Credential($oauth2)
    ->build();

$adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();

$campaignService =
    $adWordsServices->get($session, 'CampaignService', 'v201603', 'cm');

// Make calls using $campaignService.
```

when i try the code in the examples they given it give me error `Undefined variable: oauth2`

i try to put it from the connection file in session and retrieve it in the example file but not worked

one more question :

where i put the ClientCustomerId in on behalf of your client ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a while i discover the answer to my questions :

first :

> when i try the code in the examples they given it give me error Undefined variable: oauth2
>
> i try to put it from the connection file in session and retrieve it in
>   the example file but not worked

the answer of this question is in the wiki they make the code in one file. so if you want to put the code work put it in one file . and if you want to put it in other file or use one oauth2 for several files you need just to pass it

via route request

or via middleware

(laravel 5.* `$request->attributes->add(['the_name_you_want' => $client]);` 
and you can retrieve it via this code `$client = \Request::get('the_name_you_want')` )

for the second question :

> where i put the ClientCustomerId in on behalf of your client ??

this is easy to find just put it in the selector part like this

```
$session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
    ->fromFile()
    ->withClientCustomerId('xxx-xxx-xxxx') //change it to what you want
    ->withOAuth2Credential($client)
    ->build();
```

and this is the final of my questions

thanks for helping for who's try to ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are missing a small step. you need to OAuth2 instance as indicated in the tutorial like,

```
session_start();

$oauth2 = new OAuth2([
    'authorizationUri' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
    'tokenCredentialUri' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    'redirectUri' => '****',
    'clientId' => '****',
    'clientSecret' => '****',
    'scope' => '****'
]);
```

ClientCustomerId should be placed in adsapi_php.ini file which you can find on [Github](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/adsapi_php.ini).

Comment: thank you for you effort but i refer to the wiki in the question and i know its work and i get the refresh token => i didnt forget the first part of it . my question is how to use it in other pages ??? did i need to write the code in each page ????? @cevizmx